# git checkout not restore to previous status

Tags: git

i want to learn git

and

use `git init`

and add a file named context.txt

`git add context.txt`
and

```
git commit -m "add content",
```

then i modify it,and execute again

```
git commit -m "modify content"
```

and i want to restore previous content,

so execute `git log`

display

> commit e407bca38f2d609f073516624222d613b7072f71 Author: wyxz125
>    Date:   Wed Oct 22 22:21:09 2014 +0800
>
> ```
> add context
> ```

and `git checkout "e407bca"`
but the content file is not restore previous version...it is still same.,

so what can i do?thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Git, you have to add file contents to your staging area before you can commit them. If the file is new, you can run git add to initially add the file to your staging area, but even if the file is already "tracked" - ie, it was in your last commit - you still need to call git add to add new modifications to your staging area.

In a nutshell, you run git add on a file when you want to include whatever changes you've made to it in your next commit snapshot. Anything you've changed that is not added will not be included - this means you can craft your snapshots with a bit more precision than most other SCM systems.

so after commit,

```
git add  context.txt --git add to add new modifications to your staging area.
```

and then

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

or use shortcut

```
git commit -am "comment"
```

git commit -a automatically stage all tracked, modified files before the commit
If you think the git add stage of the workflow is too cumbersome, Git allows you to skip that part with the -a option. This basically tells Git to run git add on any file that is "tracked" - that is, any file that was in your last commit and has been modified. This allows you to do a more Subversion style workflow if you want, simply editing files and then running git commit -a when you want to snapshot everything that has been changed. You still need to run git add to start tracking new files, though, just like Subversion.

reference [git reference](http://gitref.org/basic/#commit)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on the second commit "modify content" you did not add anything to the index and the commit was not performed (you confirmed this using `git log` you had only one entry there). That is why the working directory remained the same, even when doing a checkout. 
You either should do another `git add content.txt` or use `git commit -a -m "modify content"`.

Comment: I believe he is asking how to return to state of previous commit, not to make amends to already existing one

Comment: No, he was questioning why the checkout did not restore the previous commit and the issue was that he didn't made another commit.

Comment: Wait a minute... He writes that he make two commits... Could You explain this to me precisely please ? If i mistaken i should then remove my answer (or alter it) Thanks in advance

Comment: @4rlekin Please see my updated answer. The second commit was not made because he did not staged any changes for commit.

Comment: ok then, thanks. I just assumed that he performed `git add` and that this log is just a cutout. If he didn't then your answer is obviously correct.

Comment: @4rlekin Yes, this seems to be the scenario, if he had performed and add then

Comment: i git add it,and commit -m "a version",and checkout previous version,it work.but how can i restore to the "a version" again?

Comment: @user2245634 Before: `git commit -m "modify content"` you need another `add`, a second one. To stage the modified changes.